# Get specific row from matrix in Scilab

Tags: matrix, scilab

For example, I've created a matrix

```
a = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9]
```

and I want to extract the second row in variable r, so after that

```
r = [4, 5, 6].
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the second row use

```
r = a(2,:);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = a(2,$);
```

A very good tutorial may be found here:
http://hkumath.hku.hk/~nkt/Scilab/IntroToScilab.html

Comment: This gives you the last element of the second row, not the whole second row.